# Deferred/Stalled Engagement Letter

Tags: hiring-process

Last Monday, I prompted my new employer that I accepted their offer, and they were very responsive.

I completed the process (filling out information and providing scanned copies of some documents) on the morning, and I expected to receive an invitation in the afternoon to go get the engagement letter.

However, I sensed some kind of abnormal latency.

Due to the fact that I was terminated before the end my probation with my previous employer, I was worried something would impact the hiring process with this new employer.

I gave them a call yesterday, and they sounded normal, stating that my document is ready, it just needs to be signed by some upper management guy.

The thing is that, I gave my new employer a 2 weeks notice, and I theoretically am not supposed to resign until I get the signed letter.

Have they intercepted an information of concern, and they are cancelling my hiring?

Or does this sound pretty normal?

Comment: I'm confused. Why would you give a 2 weeks notice to the new employer? Are you saying that you were terminated from a job, then got a new job (employer A), then you got another job (employer B) and now you quit employer A, but employer B hasn't given you a letter yet? If so, can you update your question to include employer A, employer B so that it is clearer?

Comment: No, I was terminated, but new employer presumably doesn't know. Assuming they don't know, they should give me the engagement letter ASAP so that I can resign so that I can start on July 9th.

Comment: Presumably, the new employer asked you 'when is the first date you can start' at some point?

Comment: Yes, and they asked to provide some documents (bank account, picture, and a filled out form). I called on Wednesday and they told the engagement letter but someone who needs to sign didn't do it yet. I am still waiting.

Answer (score 6):

It does sound fairly normal to have upper management sign off on new hires however anything could be happeneing and we can only speculate.

As always, **never give your notice until you have your contract signed on the dotted line.** 
Purely from the point of self preservation as evidentally you are now worried about this a lot more than you would if you still had your job to fall back on.

Comment: Well, I was supposed to have the letter last Tuesday, so that I can start on the second Monday of July. This latency doesn't seem normal to me.

Comment: @Leonidas There are so many reasons why this could of happened and they have given you a reason that it needs to be signed off. Nobody is able to tell any more than that. Businesses all run differently. From my experience, this delay does not seem like something abnormal but then again, that is just from my experience and as I said, anything more is **speculation**.